# Every set of second category is everywhere dense

Tags: metric-spaces, baire-category

I just have learnt the definitions of the sets of first and second category and I found this corollary that I cannot explain to myself. Please explain how can I prove this statement.

I just know that if a set is of second category in a metric space $(X,d)$, it cannot be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets in $X$.

Comment: $(0,1)\subset\mathbb R$ is not everywhere dense and of second category. Are you sure that your question is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(0,1)$ as a subset of $\Bbb R$ (usual topology) is not everywhere dense, as $\overline{(0,1)}=[0,1] \neq \Bbb R$ and is second category, being completely metrisable (or locally compact Hausdorff; whatever your favourite Baire theorem is). So your statement seems false. What would it be a corollary of? Are you missing assumptions?